# Je cherche un lexique d'argot des truands contemporain

Tags: argot, jargon

Pour donner de la couleur locale à une histoire sur laquelle je suis en train de travailler, j'aimerais employer quelques termes d'argot des truands. Malheureusement, s'il est assez simple de trouver des lexiques datant du XIXème siècle ou même des années 1970, je ne vois pas grand chose pour les générations actuelles de truands.

Je cherche essentiellement à narrer une arnaque, une attaque à main armée et les rapports entre membres d'une équipe de voleurs, son receleur, ses avocats, etc.

Quelques exemples de termes dont j'aurais besoin (ou je pourrais avoir besoin) :

- des rôles – malfrat, arnaqueur, braqueur, gorille, gardien, policier, avocat, juge d'instruction, police judiciaire, groupes d'intervention, civils, taupe, receleur ;
- des objets – arme à feu, arme blanche, coffre-fort, outils de crochetage, ordinateur, micro-espion, systèmes de sécurité ;
- des événements – être capturé, passer aux aveux, passer du temps en prison, sortir de prison, braquer/se faire braquer, arnaquer/se faire arnaquer, menacer, se cacher, fuir.

Comment: Faites un tour chez eux. Il y a plein de films et séries avec ce language, aussi.

Comment: @Lambie À quel point le langage employé dans ces films et séries est-il réaliste ? De plus, tous ces films donnent l'impression que l'argot n'a pas évolué depuis les années 1980, ce qui me semblerait surprenant.

Comment: Il faut régarder les filmes sur les banlieues. Faut dire qu'un certain verlan perdure comme muefs. Il y a un grand choix, régarde: http://www.cinetrafic.fr/liste-film/4204/1/le-polar-francais-moderne

Comment: Ne le dis à personne (film), est très bon. Il y a aussi quelques bonnes séries: Les Témoins et aussi Engrénages, policier. Plein de language flico-malfaiteur [mon invention]. Très actuels.

Comment: Vous pourriez trouver de l'inspiration dans le vocabulaire utilisé par les rappeurs actuels, on y trouve pas mal de référence aux policiers, à la délinquance, etc. dans un langage "fleuri" (zonzon, condé, keuf, etc.).

Comment: Parlez-vous keuf ?» (Editions Vuibert), sorti en 2013.

Comment: @Lambie ahah, je vais regarder, merci !

Comment: @Yorick Le rap n'est-il pas une bonne solution de secours dans les cas là ?

Comment: @MonsieurTruite – je viens d'ajouter quelques mots dont je pense avoir besoin. J'ai bien peur de ne pas tous les trouver dans du rap.

Comment: [*Dictionnaire de l’argot*](http://www.bouquins.tm.fr/site/dictionnaire_de_l_argot_&100&9782221113516.html) chez *Bouquins* pourrait être une source parmi d’autres. Je ne l’ai cependant pas lu ni même regardé, et un client d’Amazon.fr met en garde contre la dénomination trompeuse: ce serait davantage un lexique qu’un dictionnaire, et qu’on y trouve des informations intéressantes n’enlèverait rien au fait que les informations y soient éparpillées et difficiles à trouver si on en cherche une en particulier.

Comment: Sans être tombé en désuétude complète, le terme truand n'est plus utilisé pour désigner les criminels actuels; étant donné qu'il renvoit à l'image du gangster gentleman de la vieille époque.  
Ta question est très vague, surtout que l'argot diffère selon les classes sociales et les origines des criminels et leur époque. Une bonne première étape serait de lire des dépositions publiées et des romans policiers.

Answer (score 4):

I can't think of a website that matches words with their slang equivalent.
However, maybe you can do something with this by wandering...
Type any word on the search bar on the top right, and then you can go for a random word. Maybe you'll stumble upon one you can use

https://www.dictionnairedelazone.fr/

EDIT :
Even better, go directly here in the website :
https://www.dictionnairedelazone.fr/glossary/lexical

so you can pick a word you're interested in and see if it has a slang equivalent. You can even get real examples of usage (mostly in french rap songs)